# Tabs within accordion Jquery

Tags: jquery

I use tabs within accordion from jquery ui. 
You can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vk88/pSMQy/2/)

My problem is that i want to run the first tab results when the user click on the row (`h3` tag) and only this tab.
The code as it is implementing now make the call for the first tab for all rows.

Thank you in advance!

vk

Comment: [something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/pSMQy/3/)

Comment: Thank you Pete! This is what i want!

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({                       
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible:true,
    active:false,
    activate: function( event, ui ) { 
        var active = $(this).accordion( "option", "active" );
        $('#tabs-' + active).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) { 
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {                 
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                }); 
            }   
        }); 
    }   
});
```

The idea is to assign your tab an id corresponding to its row and on activate event, you select this id through the accordion API, and by extension the tab container, then activate it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/limdauto/pSMQy/5/